# Assign custom fields to multiple posts?

Tags: custom-field

I'm looking for a quick way to assign custom fields to a selection of posts that I hand pick. What's the best way to go about this?

Currently I'm forced to edit each page and manually add the custom field. There's got to be a better way. And no, I don't want to apply it to a post type or a category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [magic fields](https://github.com/magic-fields-team/Magic-Fields-2) plugin. That is the best custom fields plugin i've tried so far

Comment: I just don't see how that solves my problem. How can you assign a custom field across multiple pages?

Comment: Have you tried that plugin?

Comment: So far, I understand that you create a group and then assign custom fields to the entire group. I'm not quite sure how to import existing pages into groups, share pages between groups...